# props is undefined react, trying to access props passed in a stateless component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to access a passed down prop in a stateless component. The situation is something like this:
This is the parent component:

```
function Parent(){
 const [value, setValue] = React.useState(true);

return (
  <Child value={value} />
)
}
```

This is the child component:

```
const Child = (props)=>{
// the line of code I didn't see as related to the problem:
  const [otherValue, setOtherValue] = React.useState(true); 
  console.log(props.value);
 return (
   // some code that uses the value of the prop to show something
)
}
```

All I'm getting is that the props is undefined. I've looked other questions here and I've read an article which according to it I'm correct in the way I'm trying to access the props, or am I wrong? Can someone help me here?

**SOLUTION:** I just tried to turn my child component into a class component, because my Child component contained a state that at first I didn't find relevant to put it into my example code shared here. So when I turned it into a class component everything worked ok.

So now my question is  why, how does it work like this, do function and const components not hold two states or states and props at the same time?

the structure of the code now is like this: 
This is the parent component:

```
function Parent(){
 const [value, setValue] = React.useState(true);

return (
  <Child value={value} />
)
}
```

This is the child component:

```
class Child extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
     otherValue: true  
  }
  }

  render(){
    console.log(this.props.value);// prints true just fine
    return (
       // some code that uses the value of the prop to show something
    )

  }
}
```

Comment: With that code snippet what you have shared, I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: The console log give me "true", not "undefined".

Comment: I really dont't understand I mean I have other parts of the code but that doesn't relate to this access that I'm trying to make it work, and basically it's not different from the code I've shared here but again I'm just getting an error of props is undefined. Do you know of any reason in any scenario this kind of access could not work?

Comment: Your code looks right. Can you create a reproducible example on CodeSandbox/Codepen?

Comment: @helloitsjoe I edited the question with the solution but don't understand the solution, can you help me?

Comment: @DA I tried your shared code before the solution section, it works well.

Comment: @Hurobaki then I have no idea what is going on, thanks nonetheless

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem with your "before" version, there could be some other context we're missing. If you create a reproducible example on CodeSandbox/Codepen of the "before" version we can probably tell you what's wrong, otherwise we don't have enough information.

Comment: @helloitsjoe I think I know now that I have a problem with the structure of my application, because i've needed to change a lot of it until this time, so I think i'll focus on that right now since certainly I wouldn't know how to write a suitable reproduced example of my actual code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that your code works fine.Got nothing to do with class/function component.
maybe you forgot to return null or element in your Child component.

```
const Child = props => {
  // the line of code I didn't see as related to the problem:
  const [otherValue, setOtherValue] = React.useState(true);
  console.log("Child", props.value);
  return null;
};
```

see working:[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-leftpad-0eeg3)